# How do I set a conditional breakpoint based on a generic type?

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

Is there any way to set a breakpoint as pictured below?
[image]

I'd like the breakpoint to trigger when `Element` is type `ProjectEntity`, but I get the following error:

```
Stopped due to an error evaluating condition of breakpoint 13.1: "Element == ProjectEntity"
Couldn't parse conditional expression:
error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'Element'
Element == ProjectEntity
^~~~~~~
```

I also can't `po Element` when that breakpoint is hit. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a local variable that assigned to the generic type, and then calling `type(of:)` on that and checking it against the type I wanted to break on.

```
let e = Element.self
let isProject = type(of: e) == ProjectEntity.Type.self
```

Then I made the condition for the breakpoint `isProject`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Normally, in swift code, you can add `.self` after a type to get the `Type` object that represents the type.

So,

```
Element.self == ProjectEntity.self
```

However, the runtime does not seem to recognise any generic type parameters, so I suppose you cannot check for such a condition at runtime.

This means that you must get something that is of type `Element` and check that against `ProjectEntity` with `is`.

```
someElement is ProjectEntity
```

Comment: `Element` is unresolved in this case though, so I'd be trying to retrieve `.self` on an identifier that LLDB apparently can't find

Comment: `let someElement = Element.self` and then using `someElement is ProjectEntity` as the breakpoint's condition made it break no matter what for some reason. See my answer for the solution I ended up going with. Thanks for your help!